Extra white space on top and bottom when printing with Star TSP 100 in ZPL
I have generated a ZPL code using Labelary
^XA

^LH0,0
^CI28
~DGR:SAMPLE.GRF,5796,46,
iU0G3V0iQ0G1IFGEV0iQ0G7IFGCV0iP0G3JFG8V0iP0KFW0iR0IFW0P0IFGEhX0IFW0N0G1GFI0G7GEhW0IFW0N0GFK0G7GChV0IFW0M0G3G8L0GFG8hU0IFW0M0GEM0G3GEH0G6hR0IFW0L0G1G8N0GFG8G0GFG8hQ0IFW0L0G7O0G7GEG1GFGChQ0IFW0L0GCO0G1IFGEhQ0IFW0K0G3G8P0IFGChQ0IFW0K0G7Q0G7HFG8hQ0IFW0K0GEQ0G3HFhR0IFW0J0G1GCQ0G1GFGEhR0IFW0J0G3G8R0GFGChR0IFW0J0G7S0GFhS0IFW0J0GER0G1GEhS0IFW0J0GER0G1GChS0IFW0I0G1GCR0G2hT0IFW0I0G3G8iM0IFW0:I0G7iN0IFW0I0GFiN0IFW0: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:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
^FO100,100
^XGR:SAMPLE.GRF,1,1^FS


^CF0,30
^FO10,250^FB540,1,0,C^FD123 Main St, City^FS
^FO10,290^FB540,1,0,C^FDPhone: (123) 456-7890^FS
^FO10,330^FB540,1,0,C^FDTax Invoice - ABN: 123456789^FS

^CF0,28
^FO50,470^FDItems^FS
^FO470,470^FD$^FS

^CF0,35
^FO50,520^FDProduct 1^FS
^CF0,25
^FO50,560^FDQty : 2 @2.00 each^FS
^FO450,560^FD4.00^FS

^CF0,35
^FO50,620^FDProduct 2^FS
^CF0,25
^FO50,660^FD0.1972 kg Net @24.00/kg^FS
^FO450,660^FD4.00^FS

^CF0,25
^FO50,740^FDSubtotal:^FS
^FO450,740^FD66.46^FS

^FO50,780^FDRounding:^FS
^FO450,780^FD0.00^FS

^CF0,30
^FO50,820^FDTOTAL:^FS
^FO450,820^FD66.46^FS

^CF0,25
^FO50,860^FDCash:^FS
^FO450,860^FD66.46^FS

^FO50,900^FDChange:^FS
^FO450,900^FD0.00^FS

^FO50,1000^FD***************************************************^FS
^FO250,1050^FDEFTPOS DETAILS^FS

^FO50,1500^FD***************************************************^FS

^FO50,1600^FD***************************************************^FS
^FO200,1650^FDThankyou for shopping at^FS

^FO50,2000^FD***************************************************^FS

^XZ


As per screenshot the above generates receipt like below:

Now when I download this as pdf and try to print with below settings I see extra white space on top and bottom:

If I change size to 72mm X 200mm then I see below print preview:

No matter what view or size I select printer always prints long white blank page on top then at the bottom the actual receipt.
I tried to change size to 72mm X 200mm then I see below print preview:


It would appear you are asking why Labelary generates PDFs with this weird page size, or why your printer handles them this way. The ZPL is not relevant at this point, you might as well have started with the PDF.

Hi @GSerg This is what I am not sure why its happening. Is it Labelary generating PDFs with extra white blank space on top or is it my printer that printing extra huge white space on top before actual printing ?

The PDF contains the proper paper size. You must have created this long paper size in the printer.

How would I have ? And how can I change it to fix printing ?

@KJ does it mean that if I print it without converting into pdf it will work fine ?



please manage x,y digits on ^FO command
